# How does jstack -F affect a running Java process?

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

I am trying to diagnose a problem where a Java web application I'm using (Jenkins) becomes unresponsive. If I run `jstack` without the `-F` flag it doesn't give me anything, but if I put the flag in to force a thread dump not only do I get a result, but the application starts responding and goes on as if nothing had happened until it eventually stops responding again.

What does `jstack -F` flag do that would affect a running JVM and cause an unresponsive application to start responding again?

Comment: Just speculation, but it might cause a spurious wake up or something similar to occur.

Comment: In order to establish what is causing the issue I would try using jdb. This way when the application is unresponsive you will be able to attach and investigate the cause.

Answer (score 16):

You can see the source to jstack [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/tools/jstack/JStack.java).  The -F argument changes how jstack connects to the jvm.  With -F (or -m) JStack connects to the jvm using the java debugger interface.  If a pid is specified, JStack connects with the [SA PID Attaching Connector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Connectors) which says,

> The process to be debugged need not have been started in debug
>   mode(ie, with -agentlib:jdwp or -Xrunjdwp).  It is permissable for the
>   process to be **hung**.

I don't know why it would cause an unresponsive application to start responding again, but the link above also says,

> The process is suspended when this connector attaches and resumed when
>   this connector detaches.

This may have an effect.

Comment: The PID attach mechanism does not require the inspected process to collaborate - it just inspects the memory structures and tries to figure what is available. It may provide less information than if asked nicely.

Comment: ok have understood why it could works better after a jstack -F.

Comment: What would change after a process is suspended and woken up that would cause the application to become responsive again?

Comment: @JordanBentley It's hard to know why without knowing why the application is unresponsive in the first place.  Is it gc'ing, swapped out, the machine itself is overloaded?

Comment: @sbridges Most of the time when I run jmap -heap on it when it's unresponsive it will show that the eden space is full so I assume that GC is going on. I turned on concurrent GC but that didn't make any difference. The machine couldn't be overloaded, it's a powerful server with nothing else is running on it but Jenkins, and the problem still occurs when it doesn't have any builds running under it. My next step will be to try a different JVM, but I'd still like to know how jstack suspending the process would alter it's execution for my own curiosity.

Answer (score 11):

jstack -F -l pid is similarly to (assume working dir is JAVA_HOME)

```
bin/java -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.useWindbgDebugger  -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.useProcDebugger  -cp lib/sa-jdi.jar;lib/tools.jar  sun.tools.jstack.JStack -F -l pid
```

and in the [sun.tools.jstack.JStack code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/tools/jstack/JStack.java#JStack)

```
   if (arg.equals("-F")) {
       useSA = true;
   }
   .....
   // now execute using the SA JStack tool or the built-in thread dumper
   if (useSA) {
       // parameters (<pid> or <exe> <core>
       ...
       runJStackTool(mixed, locks, params);
   } else {
       // pass -l to thread dump operation to get extra lock info
       String pid = args[optionCount];
        ...
       runThreadDump(pid, params);
    }
```

and since -F is passed in, runJStackTool is called to load sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack, it have same effect of invoking directly

```
bin\java -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.useWindbgDebugger  -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.useProcDebugger  -cp lib/sa-jdi.jar;lib/tools.jar  sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack pid
```

and sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack will call [sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/jvm/hotspot/bugspot/BugSpotAgent.java#BugSpotAgent.attach%28int%29) attach -> go ->setupVM method

Maybe below code is the magic

```
       jvmdi = new ServiceabilityAgentJVMDIModule(debugger, saLibNames);
       if (jvmdi.canAttach()) {
           jvmdi.attach();
           jvmdi.setCommandTimeout(6000);
           debugPrintln("Attached to Serviceability Agent's JVMDI module.");
           // Jog VM to suspended point with JVMDI module
           resume();
           suspendJava();
           suspend();
           debugPrintln("Suspended all Java threads.");
       }
```

it will suspend all Java threads in the target process.  if your application is hang for thread starvation, the suspend method call may relax them.