# suspended JVM, "jstack -F pid" only fix

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, jvm

JVM gurus,
    Need your help. I have a JVM/app that is getting into a "suspended" state. It sounds similar to this older thread:
[How does jstack -F affect a running Java process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061226/how-does-jstack-f-affect-a-running-java-process)

...but I'm looking for any further suggestions/guidance.

- its a commercial java app that (when seemingly idle - middle of the night, etc) becomes unresponsive.
- "kill -3 " hangs, no response in console.
- verbose gc log won't be written to at all.
- 'top' shows pid having low (almost no) CPU or memory utilization, low file descriptors, etc.
- jvm remains in this state indefinitely (we left it for 10 hrs once), until...
- "jstack -F " is issued, which kickstarts the JVM/app. GC logging resumes, application starts responding again, etc.
- issue has been occurring for a few weeks, near daily, to 30 independent JVMs (spread across 10 RHEL 6.6 VMs).
- sometimes it happens in a matter of hours after startup. App can be completely unused during that time.
- we've have been using Oracle JVM 1.8.0_31 for Linux x64 to date. Have just upgraded to latest public (1.8.0_72) and will see if issue goes away.

Anyone pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're likely hit by the [futex_wait bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64).

Update to a kernel that contains [the fix, rev 76835b0e](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/76835b0ebf8a7fe85beb03c75121419a7dec52f0)

Comment: Thanks the8472!  We had not heard of this before, but it does look like our issue...we've upgraded some of the OSes to RHL 6.7 and are monitoring.

Comment: FYI - after upgrading RHL to 6.7, issue was not seen for 10+ days. Thanks again the8472.